# Merge "contracts" and "smartcontracts" tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Is it possible to merge tags and should the [contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracts) and [smartcontracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartcontracts) tags be merged?

Comment: I can't edit you post; can you edit to use the markdown sytax for tags? It's `[tag:foobar]` for normal tags and `[meta-tag:foobar-meta]` for tags on the meta site.

Comment: Now done in the post.  Do you mean to also edit the question title?

Comment: @eth: You might want to add the [meta-tag:support] tag. SE Moderators might be looking specifically for that tag to see where their help is needed. – You shouldn't put tags in the title of posts. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible

Yes**,** but currently only by a stackexchange moderator**.** The minimum rep to suggest a tag synonym is [1250 rep](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tags/contracts/synonyms), [which noone has at the moment](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users)**.**

> Should the [contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracts) and [smartcontracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartcontracts) tags be merged?

Yes**.**

Answer (score 0):

We discussed it [here](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/should-we-rename-the-tag-smartcontract-to-smart-contracts) and consensus seemed to be that the merge should be the other way around.  How do we get that fixed?  I have enough rep to suggest, but there doesn't appear to be any way to downvote or delete existing synonyms.

Comment: I don't see consensus there, as at least 3 users suggested smart-contracts as main tag.

Comment: Initially I thought the tag would be "contracts", but on further thought I'd vote for keeping it as "smart-contracts".  Further explained in http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/84/42